# Google App Engine as Authentication Server for Mobile Application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, titanium

I am attempting to utilize Google App Engine as an Authentication Server for a mobile application that runs on android natively. User names and passwords will be stored in GAE and my goal is to be able to both store and verify credentials from the mobile application using GAE. Is this possible? I've looked into OAuth and JSON, but I don't think I have the proper setup for that.

Also, if I'm going about this the wrong way, please point me to the proper path.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in having a more API-like implementation in your GAE instance, I would definitely look more into OAuth. But if you are only interested in validating credentials for this one mobile application then you need not go that far.

Fortunately you can call your GAE instance over SSL, that means that you can offload all the business of handshaking and encryption. Then I would simply use either [http-basic authentication](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#BasicAA), or simply send user-id and encrypted password as parameters in the request.

On the iPhone there is a KeyChain for password storing, maybe there is an Android counterpart? Anyway, make sure to store passwords encrypted on the device and in the GAE-datastore. Send the encrypted password when validating credentials. You should never know your user's clear text passwords. That would provide a level of obscurity which I think is enough (definitely so when sent over SSL).

Then you can simply return whether the account credentials are verified or not.

Answer (score 0):

If by "storign credentials" you mean storing username and password, then I imagine you are going about this the wrong way.  Whether you are talking about OAuth or OpenID, the idea is that you never see or have access to the password (and perhaps not username either) of the delegated authentication mechanism.  Instead you receive an authentication or authorization token to do your work (and in the case of OpeniD, some meta information about the person like first / last name and e-mail address).

By the way, have you considered a 3rd party, such as [Janrain](http://www.janrain.com/)?